# how to create extensible choice parameter groovy script in dsl?

Tags: dsl, devops

how to create extensible choice parameter groovy script in dsl?

I have manually created Entensible choice parameter with following properties

Name: env
Choice provider: System Groovy Choice Parameter
Groovy Script: //script here

[Click here for Extensible choice parameter image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CuHC3.png)

I need this to be scripted in freeStyleJob dsl

Comment: Please show your work in the body of the question

Comment: Not clear .. Please improve your post

Comment: I have improved my requirement. Please check

Answer (score 0):

dsl language try like this

```
testBuild {
    script = "./bin/ci"
    environment = "nginx"
    team = "evil-devs"
    deployBranch = "production"
}
```

This could be the entirety of your Jenkinsfile!

In this "simple" example, it could actually be doing a multi stage build with retries, in a specified docker container, that deploys only from the production branch.

Correct me if im wrong